# Call a Javascript function multiple times with different HTML ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this code.

Javascript

```
 <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.selectbox-0.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#nat").selectbox();

        $("#dep").selectbox();
        $("#des").selectbox();
    });
           </script>
```

jquery.selectbox-0.2.min.js

```
(function ($, undefined) {
var PROP_NAME = 'selectbox',
    FALSE = false,
    TRUE = true;
function Selectbox() {
    this._state = [];
    this._defaults = { // Global defaults for all the select box instances
        classHolder: "sbHolder",
        classHolderDisabled: "sbHolderDisabled",
        classSelector: "sbSelector",
        classOptions: "sbOptions",
        classGroup: "sbGroup",
        classSub: "sbSub",
        classDisabled: "sbDisabled",
        classToggleOpen: "sbToggleOpen",
        classToggle: "sbToggle",
        classFocus: "sbFocus",
        speed: 200,
        effect: "slide", // "slide" or "fade"
        onChange: null, //Define a callback function when the selectbox is changed
        onOpen: null, //Define a callback function when the selectbox is open
        onClose: null //Define a callback function when the selectbox is closed
    };
}

$.extend(Selectbox.prototype, {
    /**
     * Is the first field in a jQuery collection open as a selectbox
     * 
     * @param {Object} target
     * @return {Boolean}
     */
    _isOpenSelectbox: function (target) {
        if (!target) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        var inst = this._getInst(target);
        return inst.isOpen;
    },
    /**
     * Is the first field in a jQuery collection disabled as a selectbox
     * 
     * @param {HTMLElement} target
     * @return {Boolean}
     */
    _isDisabledSelectbox: function (target) {
        if (!target) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        var inst = this._getInst(target);
        return inst.isDisabled;
    },
    /**
     * Attach the select box to a jQuery selection.
     * 
     * @param {HTMLElement} target
     * @param {Object} settings
     */
    _attachSelectbox: function (target, settings) {
        if (this._getInst(target)) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        var $target = $(target),
            self = this,
            inst = self._newInst($target),
            sbHolder, sbSelector, sbToggle, sbOptions,
            s = FALSE, optGroup = $target.find("optgroup"), opts = $target.find("option"), olen = opts.length;

        $target.attr("sb", inst.uid);

        $.extend(inst.settings, self._defaults, settings);
        self._state[inst.uid] = FALSE;
        $target.hide();

        function closeOthers() {
            var key, sel,
                uid = this.attr("id").split("_")[1];
            for (key in self._state) {
                if (key !== uid) {
                    if (self._state.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        sel = $("select[sb='" + key + "']")[0];
                        if (sel) {
                            self._closeSelectbox(sel);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        sbHolder = $("<div>", {
            "id": "sbHolder_" + inst.uid,
            "class": inst.settings.classHolder,
            "tabindex": $target.attr("tabindex")
        });

        sbSelector = $("<a>", {
            "id": "sbSelector_" + inst.uid,
            "href": "#",
            "class": inst.settings.classSelector,
            "click": function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                closeOthers.apply($(this), []);
                var uid = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
                if (self._state[uid]) {
                    self._closeSelectbox(target);
                } else {
                    self._openSelectbox(target);
                }
            }
        });

        sbToggle = $("<a>", {
            "id": "sbToggle_" + inst.uid,
            "href": "#",
            "class": inst.settings.classToggle,
            "click": function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                closeOthers.apply($(this), []);
                var uid = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
                if (self._state[uid]) {
                    self._closeSelectbox(target);
                } else {
                    self._openSelectbox(target);
                }
            }
        });
        sbToggle.appendTo(sbHolder);

        sbOptions = $("<ul>", {
            "id": "sbOptions_" + inst.uid,
            "class": inst.settings.classOptions,
            "css": {
                "display": "none"
            }
        });

        $target.children().each(function(i) {
            var that = $(this), li, config = {};
            if (that.is("option")) {
                getOptions(that);
            } else if (that.is("optgroup")) {
                li = $("<li>");
                $("<span>", {
                    "text": that.attr("label")
                }).addClass(inst.settings.classGroup).appendTo(li);
                li.appendTo(sbOptions);
                if (that.is(":disabled")) {
                    config.disabled = true;
                }
                config.sub = true;
                getOptions(that.find("option"), config);
            }
        });

        function getOptions () {
            var sub = arguments[1] && arguments[1].sub ? true : false,
                disabled = arguments[1] && arguments[1].disabled ? true : false;
            arguments[0].each(function (i) {
                var that = $(this),
                    li = $("<li>"),
                    child;
                if (that.is(":selected")) {
                    sbSelector.text(that.text());
                    s = TRUE;
                }
                if (i === olen - 1) {
                    li.addClass("last");
                }
                if (!that.is(":disabled") && !disabled) {
                    child = $("<a>", {
                        "href": "#" + that.val(),
                        "rel": that.val()
                    }).text(that.text()).bind("click.sb", function (e) {
                        if (e && e.preventDefault) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                        }
                        var t = sbToggle,
                            $this = $(this),
                            uid = t.attr("id").split("_")[1];
                        self._changeSelectbox(target, $this.attr("rel"), $this.text());
                        self._closeSelectbox(target);
                    }).bind("mouseover.sb", function () {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        $this.parent().siblings().find("a").removeClass(inst.settings.classFocus);
                        $this.addClass(inst.settings.classFocus);
                    }).bind("mouseout.sb", function () {
                        $(this).removeClass(inst.settings.classFocus);
                    });
                    if (sub) {
                        child.addClass(inst.settings.classSub);
                    }
                    if (that.is(":selected")) {
                        child.addClass(inst.settings.classFocus);
                    }
                    child.appendTo(li);
                } else {
                    child = $("<span>", {
                        "text": that.text()
                    }).addClass(inst.settings.classDisabled);
                    if (sub) {
                        child.addClass(inst.settings.classSub);
                    }
                    child.appendTo(li);
                }
                li.appendTo(sbOptions);
            });
        }

        if (!s) {
            sbSelector.text(opts.first().text());
        }

        $.data(target, PROP_NAME, inst);

        sbHolder.data("uid", inst.uid).bind("keydown.sb", function (e) {
            var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0,
                $this = $(this),
                uid = $this.data("uid"),
                inst = $this.siblings("select[sb='"+uid+"']").data(PROP_NAME),
                trgt = $this.siblings(["select[sb='", uid, "']"].join("")).get(0),
                $f = $this.find("ul").find("a." + inst.settings.classFocus);
            switch (key) {
                case 37: //Arrow Left
                case 38: //Arrow Up
                    if ($f.length > 0) {
                        var $next;
                        $("a", $this).removeClass(inst.settings.classFocus);
                        $next = $f.parent().prevAll("li:has(a)").eq(0).find("a");
                        if ($next.length > 0) {
                            $next.addClass(inst.settings.classFocus).focus();
                            $("#sbSelector_" + uid).text($next.text());
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 39: //Arrow Right
                case 40: //Arrow Down
                    var $next;
                    $("a", $this).removeClass(inst.settings.classFocus);
                    if ($f.length > 0) {
                        $next = $f.parent().nextAll("li:has(a)").eq(0).find("a");
                    } else {
                        $next = $this.find("ul").find("a").eq(0);
                    }
                    if ($next.length > 0) {
                        $next.addClass(inst.settings.classFocus).focus();
                        $("#sbSelector_" + uid).text($next.text());
                    }
                    break;              
                case 13: //Enter
                    if ($f.length > 0) {
                        self._changeSelectbox(trgt, $f.attr("rel"), $f.text());
                    }
                    self._closeSelectbox(trgt);
                    break;
                case 9: //Tab
                    if (trgt) {
                        var inst = self._getInst(trgt);
                        if (inst/* && inst.isOpen*/) {
                            if ($f.length > 0) {
                                self._changeSelectbox(trgt, $f.attr("rel"), $f.text());
                            }
                            self._closeSelectbox(trgt);
                        }
                    }
                    var i = parseInt($this.attr("tabindex"), 10);
                    if (!e.shiftKey) {
                        i++;
                    } else {
                        i--;
                    }
                    $("*[tabindex='" + i + "']").focus();
                    break;
                case 27: //Escape
                    self._closeSelectbox(trgt);
                    break;
            }
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }).delegate("a", "mouseover", function (e) {
            $(this).addClass(inst.settings.classFocus);
        }).delegate("a", "mouseout", function (e) {
            $(this).removeClass(inst.settings.classFocus);  
        });

        sbSelector.appendTo(sbHolder);
        sbOptions.appendTo(sbHolder);           
        sbHolder.insertAfter($target);

        $("html").live('mousedown', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();          
            $("select").selectbox('close'); 
        });
        $([".", inst.settings.classHolder, ", .", inst.settings.classSelector].join("")).mousedown(function(e) {    
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    },
    /**
     * Remove the selectbox functionality completely. This will return the element back to its pre-init state.
     * 
     * @param {HTMLElement} target
     */
    _detachSelectbox: function (target) {
        var inst = this._getInst(target);
        if (!inst) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        $("#sbHolder_" + inst.uid).remove();
        $.data(target, PROP_NAME, null);
        $(target).show();           
    },
    /**
     * Change selected attribute of the selectbox.
     * 
     * @param {HTMLElement} target
     * @param {String} value
     * @param {String} text
     */
    _changeSelectbox: function (target, value, text) {
        var onChange,
            inst = this._getInst(target);
        if (inst) {
            onChange = this._get(inst, 'onChange');
            $("#sbSelector_" + inst.uid).text(text);
        }
        value = value.replace(/\'/g, "\\'");
        $(target).find("option[value='" + value + "']").attr("selected", TRUE);
        if (inst && onChange) {
            onChange.apply((inst.input ? inst.input[0] : null), [value, inst]);
        } else if (inst && inst.input) {
            inst.input.trigger('change');
        }
    },
    /**
     * Enable the selectbox.
     * 
     * @param {HTMLElement} target
     */
    _enableSelectbox: function (target) {
        var inst = this._getInst(target);
        if (!inst || !inst.isDisabled) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        $("#sbHolder_" + inst.uid).removeClass(inst.settings.classHolderDisabled);
        inst.isDisabled = FALSE;
        $.data(target, PROP_NAME, inst);
    },
    /**
     * Disable the selectbox.
     * 
     * @param {HTMLElement} target
     */
    _disableSelectbox: function (target) {
        var inst = this._getInst(target);
        if (!inst || inst.isDisabled) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        $("#sbHolder_" + inst.uid).addClass(inst.settings.classHolderDisabled);
        inst.isDisabled = TRUE;
        $.data(target, PROP_NAME, inst);
    },
    /**
     * Get or set any selectbox option. If no value is specified, will act as a getter.
     * 
     * @param {HTMLElement} target
     * @param {String} name
     * @param {Object} value
     */
    _optionSelectbox: function (target, name, value) {
        var inst = this._getInst(target);
        if (!inst) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        //TODO check name
        inst[name] = value;
        $.data(target, PROP_NAME, inst);
    },
    /**
     * Call up attached selectbox
     * 
     * @param {HTMLElement} target
     */
    _openSelectbox: function (target) {
        var inst = this._getInst(target);
        //if (!inst || this._state[inst.uid] || inst.isDisabled) {
        if (!inst || inst.isOpen || inst.isDisabled) {
            return;
        }
        var el = $("#sbOptions_" + inst.uid),
            viewportHeight = parseInt($(window).height(), 10),
            offset = $("#sbHolder_" + inst.uid).offset(),
            scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
            height = el.prev().height(),
            diff = viewportHeight - (offset.top - scrollTop) - height / 2,
            onOpen = this._get(inst, 'onOpen');
        el.css({
            "top": height + "px",
            "maxHeight": (diff - height) + "px"
        });
        inst.settings.effect === "fade" ? el.fadeIn(inst.settings.speed) : el.slideDown(inst.settings.speed);
        $("#sbToggle_" + inst.uid).addClass(inst.settings.classToggleOpen);
        this._state[inst.uid] = TRUE;
        inst.isOpen = TRUE;
        if (onOpen) {
            onOpen.apply((inst.input ? inst.input[0] : null), [inst]);
        }
        $.data(target, PROP_NAME, inst);
    },
    /**
     * Close opened selectbox
     * 
     * @param {HTMLElement} target
     */
    _closeSelectbox: function (target) {
        var inst = this._getInst(target);
        //if (!inst || !this._state[inst.uid]) {
        if (!inst || !inst.isOpen) {
            return;
        }
        var onClose = this._get(inst, 'onClose');
        inst.settings.effect === "fade" ? $("#sbOptions_" + inst.uid).fadeOut(inst.settings.speed) : $("#sbOptions_" + inst.uid).slideUp(inst.settings.speed);
        $("#sbToggle_" + inst.uid).removeClass(inst.settings.classToggleOpen);
        this._state[inst.uid] = FALSE;
        inst.isOpen = FALSE;
        if (onClose) {
            onClose.apply((inst.input ? inst.input[0] : null), [inst]);
        }
        $.data(target, PROP_NAME, inst);
    },
    /**
     * Create a new instance object
     * 
     * @param {HTMLElement} target
     * @return {Object}
     */
    _newInst: function(target) {
        var id = target[0].id.replace(/([^A-Za-z0-9_-])/g, '\\\\$1');
        return {
            id: id, 
            input: target, 
            uid: Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999999),
            isOpen: FALSE,
            isDisabled: FALSE,
            settings: {}
        }; 
    },
    /**
     * Retrieve the instance data for the target control.
     * 
     * @param {HTMLElement} target
     * @return {Object} - the associated instance data
     * @throws error if a jQuery problem getting data
     */
    _getInst: function(target) {
        try {
            return $.data(target, PROP_NAME);
        }
        catch (err) {
            throw 'Missing instance data for this selectbox';
        }
    },
    /**
     * Get a setting value, defaulting if necessary
     * 
     * @param {Object} inst
     * @param {String} name
     * @return {Mixed}
     */
    _get: function(inst, name) {
        return inst.settings[name] !== undefined ? inst.settings[name] : this._defaults[name];
    }
});

/**
 * Invoke the selectbox functionality.
 * 
 * @param {Object|String} options
 * @return {Object}
 */
$.fn.selectbox = function (options) {

    var otherArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    if (typeof options == 'string' && options == 'isDisabled') {
        return $.selectbox['_' + options + 'Selectbox'].apply($.selectbox, [this[0]].concat(otherArgs));
    }

    if (options == 'option' && arguments.length == 2 && typeof arguments[1] == 'string') {
        return $.selectbox['_' + options + 'Selectbox'].apply($.selectbox, [this[0]].concat(otherArgs));
    }

    return this.each(function() {
        typeof options == 'string' ?
            $.selectbox['_' + options + 'Selectbox'].apply($.selectbox, [this].concat(otherArgs)) :
            $.selectbox._attachSelectbox(this, options);
    });
};

$.selectbox = new Selectbox(); // singleton instance
$.selectbox.version = "0.2";
})(jQuery);
```

HTML

```
 <select name="des" id="des" required> <--options--> </select>
 <select name="dep" id="dep" required> <--options--> </select>
 <select name="nat" id="nat" required> <--options--> </select>
```

the above function is working fine with #nat, but not working with #dep and #des. Can anybody help me with this? i have added the complete jQuery code used in this file.. i have used the jquery selectbox-0.2 plugin

Comment: You should mention that you're working with jQuery and also what plugins you are using.

Comment: Can you please provide your code in [link](http://jsfiddle.net/), so that we can help you better..

Comment: provide complete code praveen, Your code is correct till what you have shown to us

Comment: @praveen : jQuery is a javascript library so its extension is .js . BTW <select> tag can't be closed by </script> tag.

Comment: how can i attach the code.. any suggestions..?

Comment: @bushan: i'm sorry i got confused while typing.. its correct in the original code...

Comment: Hey P - just let us know what you expect '.selectbox();' to do.  lets start with that.  how it is malfunctioning?

Comment: i have added the complete code in the main post...

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you have another element somewhere on the page that using the same id "des", "dep"?

And as zero298 mention, please post which plugin you are using (if any)

Comment: you should comment it.

Comment: Sorry but I don't have enough reputation yet for comment. :(

Comment: i am using the jquery.selectbox-0.2 plugin

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to edit and post your full code (or better yet a link to a JS Bin or JS Fiddle so we can see.) Without more information, we don't know which select box plug in your using or what your HTML actually looks like. I'm guessing that it isn't exactly as you've posted since each of the select tags need to end with /select not /script. (That might well be your issue, or there again you just typed in an abbreviated form by hand here.)

One other suggestion that might be helpful - You should be able to combine your selectbox calls into one jQuery selector like this:

```
$('select').selectbox();
```

or:

```
$('#nat', '#dep', '#des').selectbox();
```

or:

```
$('.somesharedclassname').selectbox();
```